# Composer install, PHP extension GD is missing

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

So I'm trying to deploy my git project to my linux server. After I cloned it I'm trying to do a composer install to get everything up and running but I'm getting an error doing so.

> brianmcdo/image-palette dev-master requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.

Trying to fix this I'm running:

```
yum install php-gd
```

Yet giving me another error saying:

> Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I have PHP 5.5.30 on my server, I don't know if that has to do anything with it?

Does anyone know how I can fix this error and get my project running like it's supposed to?

Comment: Well, try removing php common for 5.4 : `yum remove php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64` see if that helps.

Comment: I tried this but it said that there's no package named like that: No Match for argument: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
No Packages marked for removal

Comment: Search for it with something like this: `rpm -qa |grep php-common`

Comment: The only one it returns is the good one it seems: `php55w-common-5.5.30-2.w7.x86_64`. Thanks for taking the time to help btw.